# OllyDbg not properly interpreting SSE2 instructions and operands

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, disassembly, ollydbg

Note: using OllyDbg v1.1

I'm attempting to reverse engineer a subroutine in a program that likely employs some sort of techniques to frustrate the process beyond the basic 'IsDebuggerPresent'.

I have the code disassembled in IDA, but certain instructions aren't being identified as any valid instruction by OllyDbg. This occurs a number of times, and often causes later instructions to mess up their alignment. Note that the code executes, I just can't set breakpoints in the region I need to in order to look at a particular value on the stack before a specific function call.

In particular, the instruction which IDA disassembles as SSE2 `movq [ebp+var_DF4], xmm0` seems to be problematic (see below).

Given `var_DF4 = -0x0DF4`, I think Olly should be identifying it as
`MOVQ QWORD PTR [EBP-0xDF4],XMM0` like IDA does.

I tried to force Olly to do this by manually attempting to assemble the instruction, but I got the error 'Command Does Not Support Given Operands.'

Here is the successfully disassembled code seen in IDA:
[image: Here is the successfully disassembled code seen in IDA]

Here is what Olly shows:
[image: Here is what Olly shows]

Comment: I'd try to use less dated debugger, x64dbg for instance.

Comment: I updated your question with more details, specifically that your movq is an SSE2 instruction.

Answer (score 3):

`movq` is an SSE2 instruction (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movd:movq).  xorps and movups are SSE1 instructions, so it seems your version of Ollydbg only knows about SSE1.

That would explain everything you're seeing, and **the only solution is to use newer software that knows how to disassemble the instruction set extensions your code uses.**

From the disassembly, it's pretty clear that Ollydbg just gives up at the 2-byte `0F D6` opcode with a `66` prefix.  It treats that as the end of an instruction it doesn't know.  (`66` is the operand-size prefix, and is a "mandatory prefix" as part of the encoding for `movq`.)

It doesn't assume the unknown instruction has a ModRM byte, so it starts decoding again at the `85` byte, which was supposed to be the ModRM for your movq, but if you start decoding there it's the opcode for [`TEST r/m32, r32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test), so that's what Olly sees.  The displacement bytes get decoded as ModRM and SIB for that `test`, leaving two displacement bytes (FF FF) left, which get decoded as another unknown instruction.

Answer (score 1):

OllyDbg not properly interpreting SSE2 instructions and operands
that's right! but

You could try the super mature and professional tool OllyDbg version 2.01
https://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html

It knows very well how to take care of XMM/YMM registers
as well as its Disassembler supports integer, FPU, MMX, 3DNow, SSE1-SSE4.1 and AVX operands